# Store and Retrieve time-range From MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, time

Great Sunday to you. I am seeking recommendations on how to store time range data in MySQL for retrieval and display in essentially the same table that can be updated if necessary. The user chooses a time in the format 00:00 am/pm (`date('g:i:s a', $time)`)from drop down lists in the rows in each day column, the form name of each entry being a TIMESTAMP. The entry is indexed on the hidden col/field, userID.

For example a user could store multiple selections like From: 06:00 am To: 09:00 am Sun; From: 08:00 am To: 11:00 am Mon and so on.

(EDIT) I am storing user data: name, address, job skill, availability. The table above is to store the users' availability.

See the text layout of the table:

Time Range | Sun | Mon | Tues | Wed | Thu | Fri | Sat 
AM From:
AM To:
PM From:
PM To:
Night From:
Night To:

Thanks.

Comment: @Fred tell me what you don't understand and I'll clarify. I want to find out what times people are available from in the morning, afternoon and night on days they may be available.

Answer (score 0):

So, for each user and day of week, you want to store three time ranges? You might simply create a column for each entry in your grid, like "sun_am_start", "sun_am_end", "mon_am_start", etc., for a total of 42 columns. A little unwieldy, but straightforward. To represent times, you can use any standard time format. Maybe like seconds or minutes since midnight.

It's worth asking whether you really need such a rigid delineation into days and morning/noon/night, with only one range being possible in each. Because it would be much simpler to represent each range as an entry in a `Ranges` table.

Be careful about timezones here. It's often a good idea to make tz explicit in an application like this right from the start, even if you don't think you'll need it.

Comment: 42 columns seem, as you said, unwieldy. Does anyone know of a more economical way? This is why I am seeking help.  I'm collecting the Unix timestamp for the particular time shown to the user. Eg, 6:00 am has a timestamp value of 1464494400 and noon 1464516000, converted to users by PHP date(). Thanks for the reminder on time zones. I'll restrict to EST/EDT.

Comment: I'm trying to grasp your suggestion of representing each entry as an entry in a Ranges table while giving the user the option of selecting his/her  availability in the time period in increments of 30 mins or an hour.

How do I show the user the options to select whether they're available over one, two or three spans of the day?

Comment: This is getting a bit broad for a good SO question. In short, a Ranges table would be keyed by user and another id representing the range. And it would have a column for start and end. To get all of a user's ranges, just select all rows grin that table for that user. Limiting each user to a certain number of ranges or whatever, that will happen in your application code.

Comment: Well yes,we're drifting away from the original question which was how to store and retrieve a possible 42 selections by any one user in an efficient way. I think I'll store a set of delimited values in a text or varchar field for each user and figure out how to unscramble that rather than restructuring the source of the time ranges that's not a real issue.

At the end of it all I must be able to tell the availability of "n" number or people for assignments over three periods of a day for every day of the week. Thanks for your guidance.